# UIWebView scrollView.contentSize.height not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

After load htmlString, contentSize of scrollView in `UIWebView` don't changed. In other my viewControllers all good, but now it's something mysterious

I have

```
UIWebView *contentWebView;
```

I make it in some method

```
- (void)makeContent
{
    ...
    contentWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, imageView.originY + imageView.height + 5, mainView.width - 10, 100)];
    contentWebView.delegate = self;
    contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    contentWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    NSLog(@"%@", factDict[@"text"]);
    [contentWebView loadHTMLString:factDict[@"text"] baseURL:nil];
    contentWebView.height = contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    [mainView addSubview:contentWebView];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f ", webView.height, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height, contentWebView.height, contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    [webView sizeToFit];
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f ", webView.height, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height, contentWebView.height, contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
...
}
```

Early in other controllers `contentWebView.height = contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;` help me, but now it's not work

In log I have next

[image]

So I don\t understand why contentsize.height not changed

**EDIT**

In my another viewcontrollers all good

```
- (void)makeScrollView
{
    CGFloat width = [Utils widthOfMainViewForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    [mainView removeFromSuperview];
    mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.width - width) / 2, 15, width, 100)];
    mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    if ([self.fullInfoDictionary[@"content"] length]) {
        contentWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 4, mainView.width - 12, 100)];
        contentWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
        contentWebView.delegate = self;
        HelperDf.htmlString = self.fullInfoDictionary[@"content"];
        [contentWebView loadHTMLString:self.fullInfoDictionary[@"content"] baseURL:nil];
        contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [mainView addSubview:contentWebView];
    }
    [self.scrollView addSubview:mainView];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    contentWebView.height = contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", webView.height, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height, contentWebView.height, contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    [self reloadFrames];
}
```

i have next

[image]

I get htmlString from this controller

```
HelperDf.htmlString = self.fullInfoDictionary[@"content"];
```

And set in my first UIWebVIew but results - NO.

You can it's no matter if stay `contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` I change to YES, but results are same - in second case all good in first - NO

Comment: See my answer or not ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `NO` to `YES` your `contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled`, such like

```
 contentWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

**EDITED**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView sizeToFit];
    webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, contentWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height + 60);
}
```

Comment: not help, in other controllers I set this property to NO, and I hadn't problem like now

Comment: I found answer, but can you explain me? =) I write below

Comment: This is not the answer, I have posted the correct answer below.

Comment: @TheisEgeberg - how can you saying that your answer is correct ? and mine is wrong ?? can you explain me.

Comment: Well, I tried to reproduce his error, and found it only in the case where the view wasn't added to the visible stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your view isn't visible yet. The values you are looking for are only made visible once it is added to a view which is in the view stack.

Somewhere along the way it seems that your view isn't added to at the time when you are checking your values.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it to be more readable. I tried to reproduce his error, and it only happens when the view isn't in the visible view stack. Since his problem isn't in all viewcontrollers, I'm fairly certain this is the problem.

Comment: listen `contentWebView` is a `UIWebView` and its added as subView of `mainView`, so if you are saying that `mainView` is not added on any supper view then HOW Webview will be display ?????

Comment: I've changed my answer :) it's not mainView that isn't added, it's the scrollview itself I believe. Or the webview, at some point in the flow, it hasn't been added.